# Store All Input Data Acrobat Form

Tags: pdf, adobe, acrobat

I have an Acrobat form for work that our salesmen use to create proposals for jobs and their corresponding estimates.

The problem I am facing is that the form only stores data for one customer at a time. I am trying to get it to where they can type in a customers name (or job number, etc.) and it pull up all the form data used for that customer when that exact estimate was done (no matter how long ago it was).

How can I get my PDF form to do this (save current and all previous inputs) and not just save the current data in each editable field at a time?

I currently use Omniform and it does all of this; however, we are trying to switch over to Adobe and I am not too familiar with the software and how I can accomplish this!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do all the processing local (without server roundtrip) you would have to embed all data in the PDF itself. There are several ways to do this but I would recommend using JavaScript. You would declare this at the document level. You would handle the blur event of the customer name (or other key field), find a match among the multiple customers and populate the secondary fields.

Assuming the data sits somewhere in a database, you would have to generate such a PDF or manipulate an existing template programmatically using a library. Not sure if you are looking to a programming solution or a tool.

Here is more info on JavaScript for Acrobat:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/javascript.html

Comment: I'm going to look into that! I appreciate your answer.

With that being said, is there a better "form" program that does this without all the programming? Also, would you recommend Access for the DB manager? Thanks!

Comment: I am sorry but I am not qualified to recommend a DB. I guess it also depends on many factors outside SO's scope. I am not aware of any 'form' program that does this out of the box. LiveCycle Designer from Adobe may go a long way.